# masonry only works if jquery is called twice

Tags: jquery, masonry

So I noticed that I'm loading jQuery twice in my WordPress install and when I removed the CDN I added in my footer and just use the jQuery WordPress comes with my masonry stopped working and gave the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).masonry is not a function.

so then I tried using `wp_enqueue_script('masonry');` and `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-masonry');` to load WordPress's version of masonry, it still didn't work and also the script file wasn't loaded either. I'm not sure whats going on any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on how the two instances of jQuery are being called?

Comment: The source of the `Uncaught TypeError` is because the version of jQuery included with WordPress is in noConflict mode, the object reference is `jQuery`, not `$`.

Comment: @socki03 the one i included from a cdn that i included in my footer.php, and then there was the one wordpress included in the head

Comment: @Milo ok i will try that and see if it helps

Comment: Are they both declared through the `wp_enqueue_script`?  If the CDN one in your footer isn't, then you should look to dequeue the one from wordpress, and re-enqueue your own.

Comment: none of them are, i tried using wp_enqueue_script in my functions.php it worked with my jquery, but with masonry nothing was loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out, turns out i was missing wp_footer() in my footer, once i added that i was able to solve my problem. thanks for the help